3D point projection to 2D image plane with known extrinsic and intrinsic
I have an image with known extrinsic (R, t) and intrinsic parameters (K) and I want to project a 3D point on the image (X,Y,Z) and get the correct image coordinates (u, v). I know that the point is on 5126, 1482 coordinates.
What I have tried so far is to project the 3D point to the Camera  coordinate system, calculate the x & y prime and then calculate the image coordinates. The results I get are way off:
u: [9050.37868283]
v: [1490.14136818]
Can anyone help me understand what is wrong with my approach?
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

class NadirImage():

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Leica CityMapper-2_96616_S150051-146040_MFC150_Backward'
        self.width = 14192
        self.height = 10640

        # ----------------------- Camera matrix --------------------------------------
        self.pixel_size_mm = 0.00376
        self.focal_length_mm = 112

        self.focal_length = self.focal_length_mm / self.pixel_size_mm
        self.xo = 7095.5
        self.yo = 5319.5
        self.Camera_matrix = np.array([[self.focal_length,                0., self.xo ],
                                       [               0., self.focal_length, self.yo ],
                                       [               0.,                0.,      1. ]],
                                      dtype=np.float64)
        # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # ----------------------- Rotation Matrix -----------------------------------
        self.omega_deg = 0.09444
        self.phi_deg = -0.02652
        self.kappa_deg = -92.21505
        self.Rotation_matrix = self.rotation_matrix()
        # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # ----------------------- Translation Vector --------------------------------
        self.X =  409971.705
        self.Y = 4201193.819
        self.Z =    1480.099
        self.Translation_vector = np.array([[self.X],
                                            [self.Y],
                                            [self.Z]])
        # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def rotation_matrix(self):
        # Convert degrees to radians
        omega = np.radians(self.omega_deg)
        phi = np.radians(self.phi_deg)
        kappa = np.radians(self.kappa_deg)

        # Rotation matrix around X-axis
        R_x = np.array([[1,               0,               0],
                        [0,   np.cos(omega),   np.sin(omega)],
                        [0,  -np.sin(omega),   np.cos(omega)]])
        
        # Rotation matrix around Y-axis
        R_y = np.array([[  np.cos(phi), 0, -np.sin(phi)],
                        [            0, 1,           0],
                        [  np.sin(phi), 0,  np.cos(phi)]])
        
        # Rotation matrix around Z-axis
        R_z = np.array([[  np.cos(kappa),  np.sin(kappa), 0],
                        [  -np.sin(kappa),   np.cos(kappa), 0],
                        [              0,               0, 1]])
        
        # Combined rotation matrix
        Rotation_matrix = R_z @ R_y @ R_x
        return Rotation_matrix

# Create the NadirImage instance
image = NadirImage()

test_point = np.array([[410163.605],  #uv: 5126.559809474944, 1482.3423009603664
                       [4201284.701], 
                       [20.58]])

R = image.Rotation_matrix
t  = image.Translation_vector

point_on_camera = R @ (test_point - t)
x, y, z, = point_on_camera[0], point_on_camera[1], point_on_camera[2]

#print the point on the camera coordinate system
print(f'Point on the camera coordinate system: {x[0], y[0], z[0]}')

# Calculate x_prime and y_prime
x_prime = x/z
y_prime = y/z   

print('x_prime:', x_prime)
print('y_prime:', y_prime, '\n')

# Calculate image coordinates
u = image.focal_length * x_prime + image.xo
v = image.focal_length * y_prime + image.yo
print('image.focal_length:', image.focal_length)
print('image.xo:', image.xo)
print('image.yo:', image.yo)
print('u:', u)
print('v:', v)

EDIT: I have finally found out the solution to my problem. The issue is that the camera coordinate system (most likely) does not follow the typical conventions. So what is working is this:
x_prime = x/-z
y_prime = y/z   

But I do not understand what does that mean about the coordinate systems involved, I would appreciate any help on that.
